# Creating Chart/Graph using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I just started to work with Silverlight and wanted to know how I can create simple Silverlight  application that contains Graphs/Charts.
Also what are the component(SDK,SP1 etc) required to work with Silverlight. I am having VS 2010 installed on my machine and installed SDK 4 too but it is giving following error when tried to create application.."The Specified template not found".

Thank You....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggestion following the instructions on the [Get Started](http://www.silverlight.net/getting-started) page for Silverlight. It lists all the required components and links to the downloads.

Sounds like you didn't install [the Silverlight tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=18149).

Comment: Yes, you right...Just install tools,now its working...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://sharepointdragons.com/2011/12/12/about-the-chart-controls-in-the-silverlight-5-toolkit/) for one of the best guides on using Silverlight charting/graphing tools.

Assuming you have already solved your 'template not found' error with the answer above.